# echo an array in __toString method

Tags: php

I'm having a difficult time returning an array in my `__toString` method.

Here is my code.

```
public function __toString()
{
    $this->_libraries();
    $this->_sysConfig();

    //print_r($this->version);
    $version = implode("\n", $this->version);
    echo $version;
    return 'echo';//$version;
}
```

I have been playing around with it but no mater what I do I still get this error

```
Notice: Array to string conversion in (...)
```

Is it not possible to return an array?

this is the array i am trying to implode

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [version] => Array
                (
                    [item] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [name] => cms
                                    [version] => 1.0
                                )

                            [1] => Array
                                (
                                    [name] => TinyMCE Jquery Package
                                    [version] => 3.5
                                )

                            [2] => Array
                                (
                                    [name] => Jquery
                                    [version] => 1.7.2
                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Comment: The method is `__toString`, not `__toArray`.  You need to return a string.

Comment: That notice is coming from your echo, not the return statement

Comment: the magic method __toString its meant to return a string. why would you return an array?

Comment: when i echo out my object i want out put my frameworks version of its components

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not use `implode` on a multi dimensional array

**Example**

```
$version = Array (
        0 => Array (
                'version' => Array (
                        'item' => Array (
                                0 => Array (
                                        'name' => 'cms',
                                        'version' => '1.0' 
                                ),

                                1 => Array (
                                        'name' => 'TinyMCE Jquery Package',
                                        'version' => '3.5' 
                                ),

                                2 => Array (
                                        'name' => 'Jquery',
                                        'version' => '1.7.2' 
                                ) 
                        ) 
                )

        )

);

$version = implode ( $version, "\n" );
```

Output

```
  Notice: Array to string conversion in xxxx
```

**Demo 1**

```
 $version = multi_implode ( $version, "," );
```

Output

```
 cms1.0 , TinyMCE Jquery Package3.5 , Jquery1.7.2
```

**Demo 2**

```
 $version = multi_implode ( $version, " , " ," = " );
```

Output

```
 cms = 1.0 , TinyMCE Jquery Package = 3.5 , Jquery = 1.7.2
```

**Function Used**

```
function multi_implode($pieces, $glue, $glue2 = null) {
    foreach ( $pieces as $piece ) {
        if (is_array ( $piece )) {
            $retVal [] = multi_implode ( $piece, $glue, $glue2 );
        } else {
            if ($glue2 == null) {
                $retVal [] = $piece;
            } else {
                $retVal [] = implode ( $glue2, $pieces );
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return implode ( $glue, $retVal );
}
```

Comment: heh, i wrote something that was about twice as many lines that did the same job just now. thanks for the help with the code logic. I ran into a problem where now i need to figure out how to make a string `"$name $version"` rather than having each item on a new line

Comment: You would need 2 glues .. do you want me to implement that for you ?

Comment: would you be able to? it would be a very huge learning experience for me.

Comment: ah i see, i ran the code but i get an invalid argument passed as an array when it does a recursive loop back to the function.

Comment: Did you change anything in the code ....  tested mine with the array above and it works ...

Comment: ya i had the $glue and $pieces in reverse. So is the return output with the new version? Also I may be using the wrong $glue value. what value did you pass as the first $glue?

Comment: ya i figured it out! thanks, i almost had it right. thanks for the extra push in the right direction. My original code ran just like your demo 1, your demo 2 was the answer

Answer (score 2):

Why are you echoing the return value and then returning a PHP construct?

Just return your variable:

```
return $version;
```

**Update**

I am pretty sure you can't implode a multi-dimensional array. You'll need to write a custom callback and call array_walk for that to work.

Comment: i took the array and tried to make it into a flat string using the implode function. is it still handled as an array not a string?

Comment: Does it specify what line that happens on> If so, which line is it?

Comment: the line where I invoke the `implode`

Comment: We might need to see the value of `$this->version`

Comment: check my edit, but i think i know why its not working. i need to shift my keys up one level.

Comment: ya, thats what i figured once i saw my array. thanks for your feedback. it helped me out!